Correlation value for calculating the variance of effect size (mean differences)
This is the Stat question
I’m currently conducting a meta-analysis that primarily uses within-subject/repeated measures row mean difference as the effect size.
In a referenced study, data and code were used to investigate the absolute mean difference in lower body strength before and after a training intervention.
> https://insidethenumbers.netlify.app/post/meta-analysis/
Based on my understanding, the data structure is paired (e.g., before and after treatment) with just one treating group (PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I AM Wrong). To calculate the variance of the effect size (mean difference) in paired data (such as pre and post scores), we need the correlation values between the before and after scores. However, the function below does not have an option to input the correlation values.
My question is: Can the metacont function from library(meta) be used for both independent samples and paired samples? If it can be used for paired samples, why is there no input for the correlation values?*
library(tidyverse)
library(meta)
library(plyr)

    set.seed(10)
    study <- paste("Study", LETTERS[1:12])
    post_mean <- round_any(c(rnorm(n = 4, mean = 130, sd = 5),
                             rnorm(n = 4, mean = 80, sd = 5),
                             rnorm(n = 4, mean = 110, sd = 10)), 2.5)
    post_sd <- round_any(rnorm(n = length(study), mean = 7.5, sd = 2.5), 2.5)
    pre_mean <- round_any(c(rnorm(n = 4, mean = 100, sd = 5),
                            rnorm(n = 4, mean = 110, sd = 5),
                            rnorm(n = 4, mean = 110, sd = 10)), 2.5)
    pre_sd <- round_any(rnorm(n = length(study), mean = 7.5, sd = 2.5), 2.5)
    post_n <- round(rnorm(n = length(study), mean = 25, sd = 10))
    pre_n <- post_n
    method <- rep(c("Method 1", "Method 2", "Method 3"), each = 4)
    
    dat <- data.frame(study, post_mean, post_sd, pre_mean, pre_sd, post_n,
                      pre_n, method)
    
    dat 
    
    
    ma <- metacont(post_n,
                   post_mean,
                   post_sd,
                   pre_n,
                   pre_mean,
                   pre_sd,
                   studlab = study,
                   data = dat,
                   sm = "MD",
                   comb.fixed = FALSE,
                   comb.random = TRUE,
                   hakn = TRUE,
                   method.tau = "DL",
                   byvar = method)   

The function use random effect and calculate the absolute mean difference.

You are correct that in paired data (e.g., pre- and post-treatment measurements), the correlation between the paired measurements is essential for accurately calculating the variance of the mean difference. In meta-analysis software, handling paired samples is slightly different than independent samples because of this correlation.
The referenced study involves paired data, as it measures outcomes (e.g., lower body strength) for the same group of individuals before and after an intervention. This setup requires paired-sample statistical methods, as you've correctly identified, to calculate the mean difference and its variance.
The metacont function in the meta R package is designed for independent group comparisons (e.g., treatment vs. control). It takes inputs such as means, standard deviations, and sample sizes for two groups but does not account for the correlation in paired samples directly.  Although metacont doesn't explicitly have an input for the correlation, you can transform paired data into a format suitable for independent-group meta-analysis to account for the correlation. Here's how you can handle this situation:

Adjust the Standard Deviation:  For paired data, the standard deviation of the mean difference is calculated as:

$\hspace{20pt}
S_{diff} = (S_{pre}^2+S_{post}^2-2\times correlation\times S_{pre}\times S_{post})^{1/2}
$
​
$\hspace{20pt}$where:
$\hspace{20pt}S_{diff}$ is the standard deviation of the difference of the pre- and post-test scores
$\hspace{20pt}S_{pre}$ and $S_{post}$ are the standard deviations of the pre- and post-test scores, respectively.

Input to metacont:  After computing $S_{diff}$, you can use the paired mean difference $\bar{X}_{post} - \bar{X}_{pre}$ and $S_{diff}$ as if they were from independent groups.  Specify the same size as the same for both groups because it's the same individuals.


Alternatively, you could manually compute the paired mean difference and its variance, then input them into meta-analysis functions designed for generic effect sizes (e.g., metagen in meta.)

@
StatsStudent, Thank you so much for your time and help. I didn’t fully understand how the function would work with just mean difference value, standard deviation of the difference, and ( n ) as inputs. Could you please show me how the function would be written with these inputs? It seems like metacont is designed for two independent groups, not just for a simple t-test.

@ StatsStudent, I mean, should I write the function as foloowing:  metacont(post_n,
post_mean,
post_sd=sdiff,
pre_n,
pre_mean,
pre_sd=sdiff,
studlab = study,
data = dat,
sm = "MD",
comb.fixed = FALSE,
comb.random = TRUE,
hakn = TRUE,
method.tau = "DL",
byvar = method)

@ StatsStudent, Also, if the sample sizes are not the same (due to some people not returning to the clinic for the pre-test), how can we deal with this issue?
